# Tkinter GUI is not responding

Tags: python, tkinter

I have only one while loop and the Tkonter say: GUI is not responding. 
What I'm doing wrong ? I would like with button "Pause" break and
again with "button "Start" continue the program.

```
import Tkinter, time

root = Tkinter.Tk
class InterfaceApp(root):
    def __init__ (self, parent):
        root.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.but_state = 0

        self.but_start = Tkinter.Button(self, text='Start', command=lambda: self.Start(), width=10)
        self.but_pause = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Pause", command=lambda: self.Pause(), width=10)
        self.but_stop = Tkinter.Button(self, text='Stop', command=lambda: self.Stop(), width=10)
        self.but_start.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='W')
        self.but_pause.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='W')
        self.but_stop.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='W')

    def Start(self):

        while True:
            print "X"
            time.sleep(2)
            if self.but_state == 1:
                break
            else:
                continue

    def Stop(self):
        self.but_state = 1

    def Pause(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = InterfaceApp(None)
    app.title("MPW4 microHP - Long Term Test")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I guess the `while` loop blocks any incoming event from the other buttons, so you never have the opportunity to set `self.but_state` to 1. You can try using the [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module.

Comment: Well, it's not a good idea to use infinite loop (`while True:`) inside Tkinter at all. It will stop responding of course.

Comment: But before the infinite loop, the problem is @MirzaGrbic has put the program body (buttons) in a wrong place (inside `initialize`) -- it has to be inside the constructor (`__init__`) instead.
Another problem is lamdba functions have not been defined properly.

Comment: @ParvizKarimli it's ok since `initialize` is called from `__init__`

Comment: @Frodon that's right, I just noticed `self.initialize()` inside `__init__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is nonsense. You have to figure out how to define functions and use them properly first. I wrote a little example for you:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.startb = Button(master, text="Start", command=self.startf)
        self.startb.pack()

        self.pauseb = Button(master, text="Pause", command=self.pausef)
        self.pauseb.pack()

        self.stopb = Button(master, text="Stop", command=self.stopf)
        self.stopb.pack()

    def startf(self):
        print("Started")
        self.after_id = self.master.after(1000, self.startf)

    def pausef(self):
        if self.startf is not None: # to handle any exception
            self.master.after_cancel(self.after_id) # this will pause startf function -- you can start again
            print("Paused")

    def stopf(self):
        if self.startf is not None:
            self.master.after_cancel(self.after_id)
            self.startf = None # this will stop startf function -- you cannot start again
            print("Stopped")



root = Tk()
myapp = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Then you can modify this code -- change the behaviors of the functions etc. If you have a working piece of code which will behave as the "motor" function that does the core idea of your program, include that function in as well, and return it in the `startf` function, pause it in the `pausef` function, and finally, stop it in the `stopf` function.
P.S.: My code was written in **Python 3**.
**EDIT:** I completed the code and above is a working program that starts, pauses and stops depending on the button you click.

Comment: but i would like to have the program, that when you press a start button  have to run continuously in while loop  until you press the pause/stop button.

Comment: @MirzaGrbic use `after` then

Answer (score 3):

#### First issue:

Using the while loop. To call a function again after it finished use

`self.after(<time in ms>, <function to call>)`

at the end of your `def Start(self)`

Would look like this:

```
# ...
def Start(self):
    print("X")
    if self.but_state == 0:
        self.after(2000, self.Start)
# ...
```

#### Second Issue:

Do not use lambdas for simple calls. Use the name for the binding instead, just like @Parviz_Karimli pointed out.

```
def initialize(self):
    self.but_state = 0

    self.but_start = Tkinter.Button(self, text='Start', command=self.Start, width=10)
    self.but_pause = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Pause", command=self.Pause, width=10)
    self.but_stop = Tkinter.Button(self, text='Stop', command=self.Stop, width=10)
    self.but_start.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='W')
    self.but_pause.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='W')
    self.but_stop.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='W')
```